# AWS Lambda in VPC not able to send to Event Bridge

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-vpc, aws-event-bridge

In AWS I have an account with VPC set up, and I cannot send an event from the lambda to the Event Bus.  How can I send to the event bus?  Please look at the picture below to understand our setup better.  We also have VPC peering with another account set up.

[image]

Comment: If your Lambda function doesn't need to be in VPC to access private resources in that VPC then don't configure it in a VPC.

Comment: @jarmod We need to peer this account to another account.  Can we do that without the VPC?

Comment: Not sure exactly what the requirement is for the Lambda function to connect into the other AWS account's VPC but you peer VPCs (not accounts) and you can do that with a VPN or with VPC Peering.

Comment: Yes, I guess THAT is why we have to have the VPC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The EventBridge service exists outside your VPC. Lambda functions inside a VPC never get a public IP address assigned to them, so they can't directly access anything that exists outside the VPC.

To give your Lambda functions access to EventBridge you either need to deploy the Lambda function to **only** VPC subnets that have a route to a [NAT Gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-nat-gateway.html) (which will also give them access to the Internet), or add an  [interface VPC endpoint for EventBridge](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-related-service-vpc.html) to your VPC.

Comment: Thanks, apparently my infrastructure guy added the NAT Gateway and that fixed it.